# i can't get the results in gnuplot using shell scripting

Tags: shell, gnuplot, network-traffic, ifconfig

I have to make a shell script with gnuplot to generate a data usage of my interface wlan0. Here's what I've tried :

==> for gnuplot :

```
 set title "Data usage over the current hour"
 unset multiplot
 set xdata time
 set style data lines  
 set term png
 set timefmt '"%M:%S"'
 set xrange ['"00:00"':'"59:59"']
 set xlabel "Time"
 set ylabel "Traffic" 
 set autoscale y  
 set output "datausage.png"
 plot "monitor.dat" using 1:2 t "RX" w lines, "monitor.dat" using 1:3 t "TX" w lines
```

==> and this is my shell :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 interface=$1
 mkdir -p /tmp/netiface 
 while true; 
 do
      recus=`ifconfig $interface | awk -F":" 'NR == 8 { print $2}' |awk '{print $2}' | cut -d "(" -f 2`
      transmis=`ifconfig $interface | awk -F":" 'NR == 8 { print $3}' |awk '{print $2}' | cut -d "(" -f 2`
      date=`date +%M:%S`
      echo -e "$date $recus $transmis">>/tmp/netiface/monitor.dat
      sleep 1
 done
```

===> monitor.dat

```
 08:18 823.6 121.4
 08:19 823.6 121.4
 08:20 823.6 121.4
 08:21 823.6 121.4
 08:22 823.7 121.5
 08:23 824.3 121.5
 08:24 824.6 121.5
 08:25 824.6 121.5
 08:26 824.6 121.5
 08:27 824.6 121.5
 08:28 824.6 121.5
 08:29 824.6 121.5
 08:30 824.6 121.5
 08:31 824.6 121.5
 08:32 824.6 121.5
```

but when I execute all of this, I get the following result:

[image: current graph, no lines visible]

How should I change my script so that my data is plotted correctly?

Comment: An OK question from the `gnuplot` point of view, but please, take 2 hrs to work thru an awk tutorial. Your code can be reduced to something like `ifconfig $inter | awk -F":" 'NR==8{split($2,fld2," "); split($3, fld3," ") ; print substr(fld2[2],2) , substr(fld3[2],2)}' > outfile`. Good luck.

Comment: Try to remove the extra quotes when setting the timefmt and the xrange, `set timefmt "%M:%S" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it in the console? I get a warning about an empty x range.

Your xrange is causing problems. It looks like there's some time problem. 
Try setting `set xrange [*:*]` and  you'll see the data. Experimenting with range values should tune you in to the right ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Just don’t use so many quotes:

```
set timefmt "%M:%S"
set xrange ["00:00":"59:59"]
```

Bonus: your output will look nicer using:

```
set format x "%M:%S"
set xtics "15:00"
```

[image: Result example]

(I changed the last point in your example file to get more than tiny little line.)